# Applying skin tones to emojis (web)

Tags: html, unicode, emoji, emojione, emoji-tones

I'm trying to use the [emojione](http://emojione.com/demo/) tones with unicode and when you use shortnames with `_toneX` in them, e.g., `:haircut_tone4:` two unicodes are rendered (see image). How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, support for skin tones is based on the system displaying the characters and the font being used. If they don't support the latest standards in Unicode, the fallback you're seeing is displayed.

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Diversity